# simple Youtube iframe API right out of the documentation, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

http://jsfiddle.net/y2Y5k/
I'm trying to make a simple youtube player with the javascript API and I'm doing something wrong.

In that fiddle, Im just using the exact code snippets from the documentation provided by google.

I loaded the api as a source.

I placed a div with the id 'player'.

**What did I do wrong here?**

```
<body>
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What does happen? What error do you get?

Comment: No error, just no player shows up @putvande

Comment: I added your code to a .htm on my Desktop and added <html> </html> and it works.

Comment: @tofutim You're right it was something in my page messing it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because Fiddle. All JavaScript you put in there is encapsulated in other functions (probably `window.onload` or something).
Therefore Youtube can't get to your `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function.

Just try this outside Fiddle. It will work.

Comment: Ah ok, must be something in my page messing me up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the top left side, from Frameworks & Extensions, select No wrap - in  instead of onLoad.

That will give you the result as expected.